# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: dataSource. Editing Datagrid and Save to Database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, datagridview, editing

Hello I'm having a problem here. The code looks like this.

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     string connectionString =
     "Server=localhost;" +
     "Database=oroderm;" +
     "User ID=root;" +
     "Password=root;" +
     "Pooling=false";
     string query = "Select * from client";
     MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
     MySqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
     conn.Open();
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     MySqlCommandBuilder cBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(dAdapter);

     dAdapter.Fill(ds, "client");

     BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
     bSource.DataSource = ds.Tables["client"];
     dataGridView2.DataSource = bSource;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataTable dt = ds.Tables["client"];
     this.dataGridView2.BindingContext[dt].EndCurrentEdit();
     this.da.Update(dt);
}
```

So what I want is that whenever I edit the values in my Datagrid it will affect my database after I click button1 (save button). ex. If I have roman as the client after I changed his name and I click button1 it should change. However Im getting a value cannot be null error. Please can somebody help. T_T

*EDIT: Heres the Updated Code

```
private MySqlDataAdapter _da;
        private DataTable _dt;
        private DataSet _ds;

 private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               updateClient();
        }

public void updateClient()
        {
            string connectionString =
             "Server=localhost;" +
             "Database=oroderm;" +
             "User ID=root;" +
             "Password=root;" +
             "Pooling=false";

            string query = "select * from client";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            _da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            _ds = new DataSet();
            MySqlCommandBuilder cBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(_da);

            _da.Fill(_ds, "client");
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
            bSource.DataSource = _ds.Tables["client"];
            dataGridView2.DataSource = bSource;
            _da.UpdateCommand = cBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            _dt = _ds.Tables["client"];
            this.dataGridView2.BindingContext[_dt].EndCurrentEdit();
            this._da.Update(_dt);

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you've got an *instance* variable called `ds`, and you're expecting the `Form3_Load` method to populate it? That won't happen - because in `Form3_Load` you've got this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

That's declaring a new *local* variable called `ds`, so unless you explicitly use `this.ds` in the method, you're not going to change the value of the `instance` variable.

I'm slightly surprised that you're not getting a `NullReferenceException` when you click on the button, but maybe you've got some code to create an *empty* `DataSet` and assign a reference to the `ds` instance variable somewhere. Anyway, changing the line shown above to just:

```
ds = new DataSet();
```

should fix this problem.

(I would strongly advise against making database requests in the UI thread, mind you, and you should have a `using` statement for your connection, but those are separate matters.)

Comment: I've already managed to make the code run by making a global variables for dataset, datatable and mysqladapter. However, I can only modify the content of my table once. I cannot edit the content of my table after I edited it once. What's the problem of this?

Comment: @rjtubera: I don't know, but that sounds like a separate question to me, with a more detailed description required and the updated code. (You shouldn't need truly *global* variables for any of this, by the way.)

Comment: Ive Put the updated code above. Thank you very much for helping me. T_T

Comment: @rjtubera: No, I suggested you ask a *new* question. Stack Overflow doesn't work well when one post actually ends up containing several questions which change over time.